# Bind DataGridView with database table

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

VS2015, C#, WinForms project, question of the beginner:

How can I bind DataGridView with database table such way that if I update any cell in the grid (or delete whole row) my changes immediately apply to this table?

For example, in [Delphi XE 7 + DevExpress Components] I can force Grid component acts like this without additional programming code, only with binding grid with table of my database.

Comment: See [Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx), [How To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you, Alex, but link to example you've posted is assumed to use "SqlDataAdapter" class specific to MS SQL Server and I use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.